# How to make Alfresco ADF work with Community Edition activiti 6.0?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I simply installed Alfresco 5.2 Community edition and installed Alfresco ADF 2 demo shell application:

https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components/tree/master/demo-shell

I deploy acitiviti 6.0 to tomcat 8 port 9999 and I also changed the admin password to 'admin' so user name is admin and password is admin to be the same as for alfresco community edition. I can login to acitiviti by going to localhost:9999.

But after running ADF demo shell app (npm start) and enable APS slider and login at localhost:3000 as admin and password admin, I get the below error when I login:

Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

So I cannot login to APS but login to ACS works fine.

How to solve this problem?

Note that it is community edition of activiti 6.0 and enterprise edition called APS cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

Activiti community edition is not supported by adf, only Alfresco Process Services is. The problem is that APS and Activiti CE have different sets of restful APIs.

However, I imagine that it is possible to extend [alfresco js api](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api) to support both, Activiti and APS through an extra configuration....

---

**UPDATE**
Starting from ADF 3.0, alfresco included a process-cloud module in ADF supposed to support both EE and CE edition of Activiti 7+.

I see that Alfresco has reworked the github project structure linked above, so here is the [new link for the activiti module](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api/tree/5c27d9aa19fa6731cf1c0d6d61aef472d5b2a0e9/src/api-legacy/activiti-rest-api). Note that I do not recommend going down that road on your own, unless you have really good reasons for it. Activiti 6 is supposed to be deprecated soon, and the wise choice is to go for Activiti 7 being a GA now, and since that one is supposed to be supported by ADF OOTB there is not much to be done there ...

Comment: Link is dead. Would you please review it again.

Answer (score 0):

Community editiion is not available for APS.

Comment: this does not answer the question. Activiti is open source software and is available as community edition. APS is enterprise edition of activiti. So your answer does not make sense. AFAIK old ADF 1.0 worked with activiti and community edition of Alfresco.

Comment: ADF never worked with Activiti 5 or 6...It will work with Activiti 7 in the future

Answer (score 0):

Activiti 6 is not supported by ADF. You can use Alfresco Process Services (powered by Activiti), or wait till Activiti 7 is released. ADF is going to support both APS and Activiti 7.